# Can one handle Multiple Post Form Actions on One View in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, forms, http-post

Just need to if i can use to form=post in the mvc view , below is the example which uses to form post , which currently doesnt works:
Edited: the jquery is submiting the form with id frmWorldPay when the image is clicked

```
        $("#pay").click(function () {
       // $("#frmWorldPay").(function () {
       if ($("#terms").attr("checked")) {
        $("#frmWorldPay").submit();
        alert("sss");
         // return true;
        } else {
            alert("Please agree to the terms and conditions.");
            return false;
        }
    });

                 <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>

                    <table id="cart" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Event
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Item
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Quantity
                            </th>

                        </tr>
                        <% 
                            foreach (var bookingItem in Model.BookingItems)
                            {%>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <%: ViewBag.Name %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%: Product.Description %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%: bookingItem.Quantity%>
                            </td>

                        </tr></table>
                        <%  } %>
                     <% { %>  if (ViewBag.mode == "confirm")
                       { %>
                            <input type="submit" value="Confirm" />
                    <% } %>


                    <form method="post" action="https://secure.wp3.rbsworldpay.com/wcc/purchase" id="frmWorldPay">

                    <input type="hidden" name="instId" value="01" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="cartId" value="<%: Model.GUID %>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="GBP" />

                    <input type="hidden" name="testMode" value="100" />
                     </form> if (ViewBag.mode == "Checkout")
                       { %>

                            <div id="worldPayBtnWrap">

                   <p> <%: Html.CheckBox("terms") %> by ticking this box you are agreeing to our <%: Html.ActionLink("terms & conditions", "Terms", "About")%></p>
                        <input type="image" src="/content/images/btnWorldPay.png" alt="Pay via World Pay" id="pay" />
                    </div>
                    <% } %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have sorted out the issue , actually my input was in same post method , therfore only one form was posting while the other input was not posting , the above is modified which works fine , although it is not a clean solution , for the time being i will be happy to use , will clean it later on .:)

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple forms in one web page, but you can't nest them.

Your external form is nested inside the MVC form (the `using (Html.BeginForm()) { }`), so it won't work.

Comment: but the above example doesnt works .. u mean i shud close the html begin form then start the other form ,

Comment: I tried separating both the forms but still the its not posting the action to the https website

Comment: Try `$("#frmWorldPay")[0].submit()`

Comment: it still reload the page instead of redirecting to the worlpay page

Comment: It gets the underlying DOM element.

Comment: What HTTP requests do you see in Firebug and Fiddler?

Comment: how to check the http request  in firebug ?

Comment: all Get request are of images css and scripts

Comment: @SLaks let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1012/discussion-between-muhammad-awais-and-slaks)